# php regex: how to match number + letters + Chinese

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to handle the string which got letters, numbers, Chinese and some punctuations and left number, letters and Chinese only like below

**raw string**

```
a>b%%c##1@23测$$试??\\:.##,,？？！！
```

**result**

```
abc123测试
```

for Chinese, `preg_replace('/\P{Han}+/u', '', $text)` works perfectly

```
测试 // result
```

and for number and letters, `preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', '', $text)` works too.

```
abc123 // result
```

But how can I combine them?

why `preg_replace('/[\P{Han}]|[0-9a-zA-Z]/u', '', $raw);` doesn't work as expected?

Thanks a lot for anyone help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
preg_replace('~[^0-9a-zA-Z\p{Han}]+~u', '', $raw)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDblJC/1).

The `[^0-9a-zA-Z\p{Han}]+` is a negated character class that matches any one or more chars other than ASCII digits, ASCII letters and any Chinese chars.

It is important to use the `u` flag with this pattern, as your input is Unicode strings.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/NUFaX):

```php
$raw = 'a>b%%c##1@23测$$试??\\:.##,,？？！！';
echo preg_replace('~[^0-9a-zA-Z\p{Han}]+~u', '', $raw);
// => abc123测试
```